# How can I create an authenticated scraper for Amazon product detail in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm creating a script that grabs all the shipped items from Amazon and notifies me.

Authentication is needed to see the products though.
I've already tried sending a post request through "request" which returns an error because of the cookies and extra parameters needed.

It would be easy using cheerio afterwards to get the data if the authentication works.

Does anyone have any idea on how we can authenticate successfully?

The link from the email is: https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin/185-3199906-8918341?_encoding=UTF8&accountStatusPolicy=P1&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyour-account%2Forder-details%2F185-3199906-8918341%3Fie%3DUTF8%26eoid%3D1%253A1%253Arv%252FYwjiYmnOZY9MYltVnDyf2l6p5pMkMx9deoUeiiw%252FKpPrtZrWqs5l1GGQPVb%2520qaJqHXyCkPEpLZnmDZamKkVDWhtu3dKlW5Gx7Uvxtzs0xlPJ25vduijJrPpHt79P%2520RRZHopOtAyOP4s82VLoeeiDQgq%2520FCP540H%2520UYAV7goZQxB29WObWAVh8VveTwEeWenY3sTx8ZI9%252FBLM2BSqS3IUIURW8mzMnAB9t7wglUiAcoR%252FcUhSIx%25201eNV4MspVAp7fLkeANag72BxgmsjFfRhnsxfji1VhZXLawqFeK9SBnvbUfkNWUC%2520IXWh6VcuoStBG3x%2520ZUkzGHw1ORi4J%2520Hg%253D%253D%26orderID%3D105-6914722-5422613%26ref_%3DTE_simp_on_T1&pageId=webcs-yourorder&showRmrMe=1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee any of the form input values of the sign in page.  So you must also scrape the login form.

Here is the process:

1. In your server, make Request to the URL in your question
2. Using Cheerio parse the DOM and grab all of the form fields from "#ap_signin_form".
3. Add in your data (Username/Pass) then make a POST request to the form action "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin" (This should also be scraped)

Hopefully that will get you past the login screen.  You will need to ensure all future requests pass the cookies set from login.

Now this kind of thing is clearly against most TOS's so I would urge caution in doing this kind of thing often.